# Usecase for approve and allowance functions of ERC20 token

Tags: tokens, delegatecall, erc-20-approve, allowance

Could you please enlighten me on how approve and allowance functions work using a usecase? I dont understand the underlying operations of these functions. Especially, when a token owner delegates the right to spend his token by other user: how the ownership sign-off works, is this be done automatically?

Comment: https://medium.com/ethex-market/erc20-approve-allow-explained-88d6de921ce9

Answer (score 3):

The original use case from back 2016 is that back in a day, smart contracts had no way to interact to incoming token transfer. (This has been now fixed with ERC-777 token standard and `send()`).

For you to interact with a smart contract with an ERC-20 token

1. You need to `approve()` amount of tokens on a smart contract address
2. You call a smart function that then in a turn calls `token.transferFrom()` function to take over the tokens from you and do something with them

`allowance()` is simply a function to check what's the current `approve()` limit.

Comment: Thanks Mikko! This means, the contract that I approve would use my address to sign-off tokens which require signing-off using my private key right? Does the signing-off happen seamlessly?

Comment: After the `approve()` has been done the smart contract is free to use the tokens and one can consider "the posession of" tokens to be on the smart contract. `approve()` is the only transaction that depends on your private key. Smart contract can control the tokens until you cancel to `approve()` by setting it to zero.